# Popper styled_default is not a function Mui 5.6.0 [material-ui]

Tags: material-ui

After upgrading from @mui/material 5.5.0 to 5.6.4 my vite react-ts app doesn't run, throwing an error: styled_default is not a function by Popper.js, the popper component is being used by an autocomplete component

The theme provider is wrapping entire app

Autocomplete is hitting an api to populate options, but a fresh vite project with mui doesn't seem to have this issue?

Any help / pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

running react 17.0.2
vite 2.8.0
mui/material 5.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me worked by change the ThemeProvider export path

after

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

previously

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work. This issue is an ongoing issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I was already using the suggested import line

Comment: @amit kindly check github issue mentioned above

Answer (score 12):

I also had a similar issue. The problem came from calling the MUI `Autocomplete` component on my React Vite app. I didn't know why the MUI `Autocomplete` component could trigger the `TypeError: styled_default is not a function` from the `Popper.js` file.

I have solved the problem using the combination by combining some answers from MUI Github on the `vite.config.js` file here:

```js
optimizeDeps: {
  include: [
    '@emotion/react', 
    '@emotion/styled', 
    '@mui/material/Tooltip'
  ],
},
plugins: [
  react({
    jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
    babel: {
      plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
    },
  }),
],
```

Comment: Thx. I had it very randomly. Including this fixed it for me.

Comment: Including only '@emotion/styled' fixed it for me
optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      '@emotion/styled', 
    ],
  },

Comment: I needed to include `@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2` in my list, but the concept worked. Thanks

Comment: omg. I send my laptop to sleep for a while then turn it on again and got this error, changed branches, restarted laptop - got the same. then added your code to vite config and this helped me, then reverted changes - still all works fine. strange bug.

Comment: i needed `'@mui/material/Grid2'` as of 03/03/24

Answer (score 7):

This issue has been closed. https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32727
Yet it is an ongoing issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with Unstable_Grid2 and none of the solutions I found worked, but then I dug a bit into the code and saw that it was using `@mui/system`. Running `npm i -D @mui/system` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not releted to the material ui it's releted to VITE, and it's worked for me

credit goes to the github issue source [github link issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32727#issuecomment-1697253782)

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), basicSsl()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['@mui/material/Tooltip', '@emotion/styled'],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your node_modules. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue, as I use different package management tools for different projects, such as `npm`, `yarn v1`, `yarn v3` and `pnpm`. There is some cases where I switch the package management tools from `yarn v1` to `yarn v3`, I got this error.

As I understand(guess), projects like Material UI have complicated dependencies structure, so the hoisting problem of node modules management will bring issues from time to time, hard to exactly figure out the reasons.

So my fix is just remove the dir of 'node_modules', if it doesn't work, remove the followings completely and run `yarn`(or `npm` or 'pnpm`) again.

- node_modules
- yarn.lock
- .yarn (if you use yarn v2+)
- .yarnrc.yml (paired with .yarn/)